# How do I mock my Task object

Tags: c#, mocking, task-parallel-library, task, moq

I have a registration page which makes an asynchronous call as show below

```
var registeredAccount = await _accountServiceChannel.RegisterAsync(accountContract);
```

How can i mock the returned object, I have tried to construct like i've shown below

```
[Test]
public void Display_Validate_Account_Page_On_Successful_Registration()
{
    //arrange
    var businessContract = Mapper.Map<BusinessViewModel, BusinessContract>(_userRegisterationViewModel.Business);
    var userContract = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, UserContract>(_userRegisterationViewModel.User);

    var accountContract = new AccountContract()
    {
        Business = businessContract,
        User = userContract
    };


    _mockAccountContract
        .Setup(contract => contract.Result.Value.Business)
        .Returns(accountContract.Business);

    _mockAccountContract
        .Setup(contract => contract.Result.Value.User)
        .Returns(accountContract.User);

    _mockAccountServiceChannel
        .Setup(svc => svc.RegisterAsync(accountContract))
        .Returns(_mockAccountContract.Object);
    //act
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)_registerController.Register(_userRegisterationViewModel).Result;

    //assert
    Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("ValidateAccount"));
}
```

But i think it is not working because the I am trying to set an object that only has a get property.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ReturnsAsync`

```
_mockAccountServiceChannel
        .Setup(svc => svc.RegisterAsync(accountContract))
        .ReturnsAsync(_mockAccountContract.Object);
```

You should also make the test async as well

```
[Test]
public async Task Display_Validate_Account_Page_On_Successful_Registration()
{
    //arrange
    var businessContract = Mapper.Map<BusinessViewModel, BusinessContract>(_userRegisterationViewModel.Business);
    var userContract = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, UserContract>(_userRegisterationViewModel.User);

    var accountContract = new AccountContract()
    {
        Business = businessContract,
        User = userContract
    };


    _mockAccountContract
        .Setup(contract => contract.Result.Value.Business)
        .Returns(accountContract.Business);

    _mockAccountContract
        .Setup(contract => contract.Result.Value.User)
        .Returns(accountContract.User);

    _mockAccountServiceChannel
        .Setup(svc => svc.RegisterAsync(accountContract))
        .ReturnsAsync(_mockAccountContract.Object);

    //act
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult) await _registerController.Register(_userRegisterationViewModel);

    //assert
    Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("ValidateAccount"));
}
```

Comment: That wont even compile

Comment: What version if moq are you using?